# css hover affecting individual elements separately rather than the whole div at the same time

Tags: html, css

What I want to achieve is if i hover over heading or the glyph icon the whole box and all its elements should transform in size together at the same time. Right now i have to hover over each element individually to make them transform in size.

As you can see below - what i want is if i hover over "wrench" the "bla bla bla"

should also get affected with the effect at the same time and not
 when i hover over bla bla bla individually. Please help
Here is my HTML & CSS-

```css
.featuredBoxes {
  color: #424242;
  padding: 30px;
}

.featuredBoxes .col-1 {
  display: block;
}

.featuredBoxes .col-1 :hover {
  color: #e39329;
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

.featuredBoxes .col-2 {
  display: block;
}

.featuredBoxes .col-2 :hover {
  color: #e39329;
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

.featuredBoxes .col-3 {
  display: block;
}

.featuredBoxes .col-3 :hover {
  color: #e39329;
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="featuredBoxes">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!--column 1-->
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center col-1">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 call-to-action">

          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench wrench" style="font-size:100px;"></span>
          <h3>Wrench</h3>
          <p>bla bla bla</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--column -2-->
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center col-2">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 call-to-action">


          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone phone" style="font-size:100px;"></span>
          <h3>phone</h3>
          <p>xa xa xa</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--column -3-->
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center col-3">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 call-to-action">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe globe" style="font-size:100px;"></span>
          <h3>globe</h3>
          <p>gud gud gud</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just close the gap `.featuredBoxes .col-1 :hover` to `.featuredBoxes .col-1:hover`

```css
.featuredBoxes {
  color: #424242;
  padding: 30px;
}

.featuredBoxes .col-1 {
  display: block;
}

.featuredBoxes .col-1:hover {
  color: #e39329;
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

.featuredBoxes .col-2 {
  display: block;
}

.featuredBoxes .col-2:hover {
  color: #e39329;
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

.featuredBoxes .col-3 {
  display: block;
}

.featuredBoxes .col-3:hover {
  color: #e39329;
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="featuredBoxes">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!--column 1-->
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center col-1">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 call-to-action">

          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench wrench" style="font-size:100px;"></span>
          <h3>Wrench</h3>
          <p>bla bla bla</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--column -2-->
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center col-2">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 call-to-action">


          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone phone" style="font-size:100px;"></span>
          <h3>phone</h3>
          <p>xa xa xa</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--column -3-->
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center col-3">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 call-to-action">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe globe" style="font-size:100px;"></span>
          <h3>globe</h3>
          <p>gud gud gud</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, the spacing in css is quite important